# result value store in array or json

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I tried to solve it for a long time.

I would like to have `result` value stored in an array or JSON as one set of data.

Please help review code below. I still don't understand it right.

Result I would like to have:

```
result = ["Price Milk 80","Price Pen 30","Price Tomato 40","Price Banana 40"]
```

To use in a `for` loop and send all data as just one set.

My current result is the one below, printed out to console:

```
['Price Milk 80']
['Price Pen 30']
['Price Tomato 40']
['Price Banana 40']
```

```py
import requests
import json
import locale
import csv

file = csv.reader(open('file.csv'), delimiter=',')
for line in file:
    hd = line[0]
    url = line[1]
    name = line[2]
    headers = {
        'Referer': hd
    }
    request = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    con_str = str(request["item"]["price"])
    total_price = con_str[:-5]
    msg = (name + " " + total_price)
    result = [(msg)]
    print(result)
```

Comment: If you’re not familiar with the basics of Python, I would strongly recommend starting there. Stack Overflow is not meant to replace guides or tutorials.

Comment: @AMC Please your help review code.

Comment: do you have at least a guess where your code is not doing what you want?

Comment: @GRquanti output : 
['Price Milk 80'] <br>
['Price Pen 30'] <br>
['Price Tomato 40'] <br>
['Price Banana 40'] <br>

How can I save them into list so my output will be like: ["Price Milk 80","Price Pen 30","Price Tomato 40","Price Banana 40"]

Comment: @TanaphonPrayoonprasop That looks like HTML. Again, I recommend looking at some guides/tutorials, including ones on web scraping.

Comment: @AMC no i'm writing HTML.I just give an example. i would like to have result ["Price Milk 80","Price Pen 30","Price Tomato 40","Price Banana 40"]

Comment: @TanaphonPrayoonprasop _no i’m writing HTML._ I just glanced at what you shared in your comment above, it looks like HTML, and you clearly want to extract some values from it.

Comment: @AMC 
Can you help me from the above code?

Comment: @TanaphonPrayoonprasop I already gave you some suggestions, did you follow them?

Comment: @AMC 
Maybe your suggestion can't be applied.

Comment: @TanaphonPrayoonprasop Applied to what? To who? Considering the nature of the suggestions I made, I think it’s rather unlikely.

Comment: @AMC Applied to above code

Comment: @TanaphonPrayoonprasop Most of my suggestions are not concerning that specific code, though.

Comment: @AMC 
I hope you edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define a `result` list before loop, then append a new `result` element for each `msg` inside the loop and finally print the `result` list after the loop:

```
result = []
for line in file:
   ...
   result.append(msg)

print(result)
```